# Apache Camel Salesforce Component: Are 'Minor' Relationships Supported?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, salesforce, dto

I am in the process of migrating from Jitterbit to Camel for our data integration needs.

But I'm facing a serious issue with the Camel Salesforce Component. The SOQL query in question is:

```
SELECT      Account.Owner.Id,   Lookup(User)
        Account.Owner.Name, Lookup(User)
        Id,
        Name,
        Owner.Id,   Lookup(User)
        Owner.Name, Lookup(User)
        QualifyingRep__r.Name,  Lookup(User)
        Solution_Architect__r.Name, Lookup(User)
        StageName,
        Type,
        (SELECT
                Id,
                Name,
                Product2.Name,  Lookup(Product)
                Quantity,
                TotalPrice,
                UnitPrice
            FROM OpportunityLineItems
        ),
        (SELECT
                Id,
                CurrencyIsoCode,
                SplitAmount,
                SplitOwner.Id,  Lookup(User)
                SplitOwner.Name,    Lookup(User)
                SplitPercentage,
                SplitType.MasterLabel   Lookup()
            FROM OpportunitySplits
        )               
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won'
```

I have added `Lookup(User)` to annotate the 'minor' relationship where these exist.

The JSON returned is:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "referenceId": null,
        "type": "Opportunity",
        "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Opportunity/<guid>"
    },
    "Type": "New Revenue",
    "StageName": "Closed Won",
    "Account": {
        "attributes": {
            "referenceId": null,
            "type": "Account",
            "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/<guid>"
        }
    },
    "OpportunityLineItems": {
        "done": true,
        "totalSize": 5,
        "nextRecordsUrl": null,
        "records": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "referenceId": null,
                    "type": "OpportunityLineItem",
                    "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem/<guid>"
                },
                "Quantity": 1.0,
                "UnitPrice": 11990.0,
                "TotalPrice": 11990.0,
                "Name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYY",
                "Id": "<guid>"
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "referenceId": null,
                    "type": "OpportunityLineItem",
                    "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem/<guid>"
                },
                "CurrencyIsoCode": "USD",
                "Quantity": 1.0,
                "UnitPrice": 2758.0,
                "TotalPrice": 2758.0,
                "Name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
                "Id": "<guid>"
            }
        ]
    },
    "OpportunitySplits": {
        "done": true,
        "totalSize": 2,
        "nextRecordsUrl": null,
        "records": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "referenceId": null,
                    "type": "OpportunitySplit",
                    "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/OpportunitySplit/<guid>"
                },
                "CurrencyIsoCode": "USD",
                "SplitPercentage": 100.0,
                "SplitAmount": 23392.0,
                "Id": "<guid>"
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "referenceId": null,
                    "type": "OpportunitySplit",
                    "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/OpportunitySplit/<guid>"
                },
                "CurrencyIsoCode": "USD",
                "SplitPercentage": 0.0,
                "SplitAmount": 0.0,
                "Id": "<guid>"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Id": "<guid>"
}
```

**NB:** The query result should be scattered with names but not a single one is returned. This is a show-stopper because the purpose of the integration is to calculate commissions in another system (we absolutely must know *who* to pay).

The same thing occurs with the `camel-salesforce-maven-plugin` when generating the DTOs - these relationships are not supported there either. In fact, I first noticed the problem here, when migrating the conversion of the Salesforce DTO to the target DTO. Instead of `Opportunity.Account.OwnerId` returning a `User` object, it returns a `String`.

I raise this because `Opportunity` DTO has both `Account` and `AccountId` returning an `Account` object and a `String` respectively. If all the generated DTOs followed this pattern there would be no issue.

I believe that Jitterbit uses the Salesforce SOAP API - it all happens behind the scenes so I can't be sure. One thing *is* certain, all the relationships defined in Salesforce are available in Jitterbit, so I'm puzzled by what's happening in the Camel Salesforce Component.

Is there something I need to do to have *all* the relationships generated in the DTOs, and of course for the query to return *everything* requested?

**Update**

I've tested this in POSTMAN using a simplified query:

`{{instance_url}}/services/data/{{api_version}}/query?q=SELECT Id, Name, Account.Owner.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won' AND id = '<guid>'`

The JSON returned is:

```
{
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Opportunity",
                "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Opportunity/<guid>"
            },
            "Id": "<guid>",
            "Name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Account": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Account",
                    "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/<guid>"
                },
                "Owner": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "User",
                        "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/User/<guid>"
                    },
                    "Name": "<user name>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Whilst it's heavily redacted, the `Account.Owner.Name` path is clearly there, suggesting to me that this is a Camel Salesforce component issue.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the solution was to ensure that all the DTOs were generated properly.

In the first instance, make sure that the plugin has listed the correct object names:

```
<includes>
    <include>Account</include>
    <include>Invoice__c</include>
    <include>Opportunity</include>
    <include>OpportunityLineItem</include>
    <include>OpportunitySplit</include>
    <include>OpportunitySplitType</include>
    <include>Product2</include>
    <include>User</include>
</includes>
```

In my case I had used `Invoice` and `Product` first time around.

I then compared the query line by line and ensured that the generated DTOs supported all the relationships. *This required some hand-cranking where relationships were missing*.

For example, it was necessary to add Invoice to Opportunity:

```
@XStreamAlias("Invoice_2014__r")
private Invoice__c Invoice_2014__r;

/**
 * @return the Invoice_2014__r
 */
@JsonProperty("Invoice_2014__r")
public Invoice__c getInvoice_2014__r() {
    return Invoice_2014__r;
}

/**
 * @param Invoice_2014__r the Invoice_2014__r to set
 */
@JsonProperty("Invoice_2014__r")
public void setInvoice_2014__r(Invoice__c Invoice_2014__r) {
    this.Invoice_2014__r = Invoice_2014__r;
}
```

When the DTOs fully supported the query, everything worked as expected.

I do not understand why the DTOs required manual intervention, as all the necessary relationships are defined and observable through the Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com).